# How to mock RxJs Observable Websocket for Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, rxjs

I am creating a web app unsing Angular 4 and RxJs. In one part of my code I am creating a websocket using: `Observable.websocket(url);` function.

Here is my code:

```
  /**
   * Tries to open a websocket connection to a given URL.
   * @param url
   * @param subscription Previous subscription to this socket (it may be necessary to close it before proceeding)
   * @returns an object containing the subscription and the websocket subject.
   */
  private openConnection(url: string, subscription: Subscription): { socket$: WebSocketSubject<any>, subscription: Subscription } {
    const socket$ = Observable.webSocket<string>(url);

    // Make sure we unsubscribe from the previous socket if necessary.
    if (subscription) {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    // Subscribe the recently created socket. Note: this must be done otherwise the socket won't work.
    const newSubscription = socket$.subscribe(
      (msg: string) => this.handleIncomingMessages(msg),
      (error: Error) => this.handleErrors(error),
      () => this.handleComplete());

    return { socket$: socket$, subscription: newSubscription };
  }
```

The next thing that I would like to do, is to create an unit test for my websocket. However in order to do this I would need to create a mock websocket so that I can freely send and receive messages from it.

Does anyone knows how to do this? Is it possible to use the Angular `MockBackend` for this?

Comment: You can use `spy` to say when I call `openConnection(stuff)` I want you to return this to me. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi, yes you are right spies work very well here. I've added this to my code and eveything worked: `const fakeSocket = new Subject<any>(); spyOn(Observable, 'webSocket').and.returnValue(fakeSocket);`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please choose best answer, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As OP mentioned the answer was to use spies.

```
fakeSocket = new Subject<any>(); spyOn(Observable, 'webSocket').and.returnValue(fakeSocket);
```

Comment: how about with jest?